# igraph's Shortest Path find wrong on R

Tags: r, igraph

```
1 2
1 3
1 4
1 5
2 3
2 4
2 5
5 6
```

This is my graph information text file.

```
library("igraph")
g<-read.table("/home/emir/RRR/graph.txt",)
g<- graph.data.frame(g,directed=0)
get.shortest.paths(g, 6,4,  weights = NULL ,output=c("vpath", "epath", "both"))
plot(g)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFhuM.jpg

When i plot the graph it all correct. But When i tried to find shortest path, its not always giving me the right path. Output is =6 3 1 4. It should be 6 5 2 4. As you can see there is no edge between 6 and 3. How can i overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your graph has vertex names, and these are different than the ids you have. Drop the `name` vertex attribute, and everything should be fine. It is true that `graph.data.frame()` could be smarter about this....

You can also try adding the vertex ids in the correct order:

```
g <- graph.data.frame(g, directed=FALSE,
     vertices=data.frame(name=as.character(seq_len(max(g))))
```

Comment: Can you help me on dropping vertex attribute on this ? Or any example to how can i do that ? Thanks.